# Persist container/app in docker desktop list

Tags: docker, containers

Just started with docker on windows. It's probable something conceptual I do not get, but let me describe my issue.

I Installed docker desktop, pulled some images like SQL server, mysql, redis. All works fine.
My question is about the list of containers/apps in the docker desktop. All those above mentioned applications appear in that list and I can just easily start/stop those by clicking a start/stop button that appears when I hover over them in that list. If a container is stopped the icon turns gray and if running it's green.

Now I have build a Restull webapi in visual studio. I can build the docker image from it and next run it in docker by using "docker run --rm -it -p 44307:80 -p 44308:443 --detach " and a bunch of other parameters from a command line.
Works just fine and the container appears in the Containers / Apps list in docker desktop with a green icon.

BUT if I stop the container, the icon does not turn gray, the line completely disappears. If I want to start it again, I have to run the command from the command line again.

My question it this: how do I make that container stay in that Containers / Apps list so I can restart it again with the right parameters by just using that convenient play button and not having to type all those parameters?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example, the container is started with `docker run ... --rm ...`. The [parameter `--rm`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#clean-up---rm) stands for "*remove*" or "*cleanup*", i.e. if the container is stopped, it is also removed. Hence, if we drop the `--rm` parameter, the container should still be there when we stop it.

It should be noticed, however, that the container does not "change". Changes we make to the code are, [w.l.o.g.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Without_loss_of_generality), not reflected in the container.

Comment: Thanks so much!  I totally missed that one. Even after digging out all parameters on the docker manual in the past weeks, it did not occur to me that was the cause.